# Where does Messenger save photos when I take a photo using my Windows webcam?

Tags: windows, facebook, temporary-files, messenger

My lady and I want to be safe she won't be sharing her photos with the world when she takes one using her webcam on Windows system. Is there a file saved in the Users files or are we ok to let her use a strangers computer to take "those" photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be safe on a Windows system, i recommend not to even take photo on webcam or have on disk. It is far more than controlling a folder. Take account viruses, trojans, agent softwares, malwares and so on.